# How should we deal with offensive wording in posts?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently edited a question that used the word infidel to refer to non-Muslims. The writer is a non-Muslim. It sounded offensive so I replaced it with non-Muslim. My question is, how should we deal with this kind wording that may hurt the sentiments of an individual or a group?

Comment: As an infidel myself, I'm ambivalent to the term being used here. It's sorta like "gentile" on the Judaism site; it feels like a technical term to my ears. However, I do see how it could be an example of ["name-calling"](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). If so, the best thing is to edit the term out of posts where it serves no purpose but to offend. Replacing with "non-Muslim" seems reasonable enough as a synonym.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the first thing you need to do is figure out if it's *actually* "offensive wording". As was mentioned in comments, there's nothing *intrinsically* offensive about the word "infidel", which is basically just a synonym for "non-Muslim" in this context.

"Infidel" *can* however be a loaded term given that it is often used, particularly by extremist groups, as a synonym for "enemy". Obviously, any posts which encourage an "us vs them" approach should not be encouraged (see also: "[Be Nice](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)").

While using "non-Muslims" instead of "infidels" is probably good practice (due to the loaded nature of the latter) attempting to apply a blanket-policy here would probably not really help matters: Unless a term is clearly and undeniably offensive (which "infidel" does not appear to be), posts would pretty much need to be judged on a case-by-case basis to decide which side of the line they're sitting on.

And if you're not *sure* which side of the line a post is sitting on, I would recommend bringing that *particular* post up for review in meta. That's what we're here for.

In my experience, "us vs them" style posts are typically problematic far less for the particular words they *use*, and more for the particular way in which they're *written*. In other words, you shouldn't be worrying too much about the terms themselves, rather more on the general "feel" of the post.

Which I admit can be a very subjective thing to interpret: Again, case-by-case basis.